# Java android add timeStamp to photo on right bottom corner

Tags: java, android

I try add timestamp tp photo I do this

```
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mImageBitmap, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);
    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(resized.getWidth(), resized.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); // reading local time in the system

    Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);
    Paint tPaint = new Paint();
    tPaint.setTextSize(35);
    tPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    cs.drawBitmap(resized, 0f, 0f, null);
    float heightText = tPaint.measureText("yY");

    cs.drawText(dateTime, 0, resized.getHeight()- heightText, tPaint);
```

But now I have a date on left top corner what I do wrong ?

[image]

Comment: You are passing wrong value for x coordinate. try something like
cs.drawText(dateTime, resized.getWidth()- widthText, resized.getHeight()- heightText, tPaint);

Comment: @BhargavThanki I think that is a problem with orientation photo